# Magento 1.9 - Add custom zipcode validation on Home page

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, form-validation, zipcode

Validate a zip code field on a home page popup in Magento 1.9 style might be using jquery button click.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard Magento form validation you can do this by adding the css class `validate-zip` to your form field. That will pass the form input to the corresponding method in `validatation.js`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks we have used [mask.js](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)